# Architecture for multiple intervaled request with multiple async request in them

Tags: node.js, architecture, promise, rxjs

Imagine a situation where a user send a request to the server and then the server needs to address an outer API sending 10 request to that API, each request must be with a 1 second wait time between each of them. When each of this request is resolved and a response returned and parsed I need to send each of the response items to another outer API once each of the items is completely resolved and parsed a socket.io connection should emit the results back to the client so he won't have to wait for 10 seconds until all the requests are resolved.

How would you address this kind of situation?

Been trying to use the 'when' library, sending proxy request using 'request-promise' but still can't wrap my head around on how to construct this kind of thing.

Added a diagram:

[image]

Comment: Too many words without ANY code.  Show us your code.

Comment: What's an "intervaled request"?

Comment: Once its sent, I have to wait one second before sending another req to that API

Comment: You could try drawing a diagram

Comment: added a diagram, and please when voting to close a question please address the issues in the question itself so I can try and fix it.